# SATA drive not recognized when installing RHEL 5.1 on PowerEdge R410

Tags: raid, rhel5, sata, dell-poweredge, dell-perc

Here's my setup:
Dell R410 with Perc S100 (software) raid controller on an Intel ICH10R chipset

The first problem is that the Perc S100 is only supported on windows.

I'm trying to install RHEL 5.1.  It boots from the cdrom, but later the installer can't see the cdrom or hard drive. Both are connected to the on-board sata controller.

The only options in the R410 bios for SATA are ATA or RAID.  I don't need raid, I just want a single drive setup.

Answer (score 1):

The new 1.5.3 bios update adds AHCI mode to the SATA controller.  This should solve your problem since RHEL 5.1 includes the AHCI driver.